# Font Size in Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex

How to reduce the Font Size of Text in Rows of Data Grid in Flex ?

Answer (score 2):

Use an itemRenderer with a label and specify the fontSize style.  Conceptually something like this:

```
<mx:DataGrid>
  <mx:columns>
   <mx:DataGridColumn>
    <mx:itemRenderer>
     <mx:Component>
      <mx:Label text="{data.myText}" fontSize="8" />
     </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
   </mx:DataGridColumn>
  </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Yeah, I wrote this code in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the fontSize style property of the grid and increase the rowHeight at the same time.

Comment: I changed the font size through *.css file.